# form authentication implement with two web.config or with two loginURL or two DefaultURL

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-authentication

I am working on asp.net web application with C#.net.
I have done form authentication, which works very well for the application.
Now, I have one more section admin folder where admin have pages to access.
My question is, When normal user comes to my site he access user/login.aspx where i have done 
formauthentication.redirectFromloginpage(....)
It is working fine.

Now when admin section needs to access, admin will access 
admin/login.aspx, I have simply redirect to inner page in this section and not done formauthentication.

I want to implement formauthentication if admin is validate by system, but that will be a other page, on which i need to redirect after login.

My question, is , any way to make two different loginURL or DefaultURL which works for my scenario.

Or any other way, (may be using two web.config????)

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a need for a separate admin/login.aspx.

You can use the same login page for regular users and admins. Just use roles to separate admins and regular users. And deny access to the admin pages for users that do not have the admin role and you are all set.

Update: use the LogggedIn event of the Login control if you want to redirect them to a different page.

```
 If ( Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin"))  
 {
    Response.redirect(....);

 }
```

Comment: You seems on a wrong track, if i use one page, than also system will redirect to default page, which is different in both case. Normal Users are having "home.aspx" while admin having "users.aspx', something like this

Comment: Yes, i am aware with this solution, but this is not Formauthentication... such solution already implemented and works..

Comment: Half true, Response.REdirect(....), why not FormAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(....)      what do you say :) this is just an alternative

Comment: Well, ok, I mean Forms authentication as opposed to None, Windows and Passport...